# How to centering horizontal Image list SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to centering my horizontal Social media Image list if my backend server sending me less than 7 ımage icon.if i get 7 social media icon its looks okay but if i get 2, 3 or 5 icon I want to display them always in center position.What I mean by that ;

[image]

[image]

In second picture as you can see they look separated but I want to display them in center position like together .How can I do that ?

this is my code ;

```
 HStack(alignment:.center,spacing : 0) {
            
            ForEach(data.options ?? [] , id:\.id) { item in
                
                    if item.icon != nil {
                        
                        Image(uiImage:(item.icon ?? "").load())
                            .resizable()
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                                     Image(item.type ?? "")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.065,alignment:.center)
                                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width / 1,height:25,alignment:.center)
                                }
                                
                            
                        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.050, trailing: 0))
                        
                    }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replay your data items, you didn't share the struct, but it's working in this way:

[image]

```
struct Icon: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var icon: Image? {return Image(name)}
    public var id:String {return self.name}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var icons: [Icon] = [Icon(name:"1")]
    @State var prog = 1
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                prog += 1
                icons.append(Icon(name:String(prog)))
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
            })
            Button(action: {
                prog -= 1
                icons.removeLast()
            }, label: {
                Text("Remove")
            })
            HStack(alignment:.center,spacing : 0) {

                ForEach(icons, id:\.self) { item in

                    if item.icon == nil {

                        EmptyView()

                    }
                    else {
                        
                        item.icon!
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.085,height:UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.085,alignment:.center)
                            .padding(6)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a Spacer() to each side?  Add one just before and another just after the ForEach statement.  I think it will move them closer together.

So:

```
HStack {
    Spacer()

    ForEach {
       Code
    }

    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: it didn't work . actually it display together but  2 icon in all width  and  because of that icons look big.

Comment: You have the icons as resizable, but no further modifiers.  If you add something that limits their size (like .frame(height:50), that might help.